# Adding a new date to array while pushing the previous one down?

Tags: swift

I have a tableView where I save a date. Then I want to save another date and push the first date from '0' in array to '1' position, while populating '0' with new date.

```
var dates = [String]()

@IBAction func updatingArrat(_ sender: Any) {
    let now = Date()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd,MM,YYY  "
    let dateStr = dateFormatter.string(from: now)
    date.forEach{ dateStr in
        print("WOOOHOOO")
    }
    dates.insert(dateStr, at: 0)
    print(dates[0])
    date.forEach{ String in
        print("WOOOHOOO")
    }
}
```

By pushing this button I want to move previous generated dates down and generate a new one and put in on the top of this array.

Comment: FYI - do not use `YYY` for the year. Use `yyyy`.

Comment: What's your question? What issue are you having with the code you posted?

Comment: You haven’t asked a question...

Comment: OP, let me know if my answer works for you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var temporaryDates = [String]()
temporaryDates.append(dateStr)

for date in dates {
    temporaryDates.append(date)
}

dates.removeAll()
dates = temporaryDates
```

Replace this code with the code after you define `dateStr`:

```
date.forEach{ dateStr in //Put code here and remove these lines
        print("WOOOHOOO")
    }
dates.insert(dateStr, at: 0)
print(dates[0])
date.forEach{ String in
        print("WOOOHOOO")
}
```

Comment: it worked but there was a slight chance i had to make, unsure which one

Comment: @DamoTamo What "slight chance" do you mean?

Comment: I mean a change*

Comment: @DamoTamo Ok, what change?

Comment: actually i tried it, doesn't seem to work only saves one date

Comment: @DamoTamo Edited answer

Comment: @DamoTamo Let me know if you have any further questions :)

Answer (score 0):

You're already inserting an item into your data model at the 0 position. To animate the table view shifting down, just use code like this:

```
let insertIndex = 0
dates.insert(dateStr, at: insertIndex)
let insertIndexPath = IndexPath(row: insertIndex, section: 0)
tableView.insertRows(at: [insertIndexPath], with: .automatic)
```

(Written so you can insert your new item at whatever position you want. Just change the value of `insertIndex`.)